# OpenSSL Library issues

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, libraries

Any tasks I attempt to perform on my Ubuntu Server 18.04 machine which involve SSL negotiation fail with various errors. For example:

```
# speedtest-cli
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Cannot retrieve speedtest configuration
ERROR: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)>

# wget http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/speedtest-cli/speedtest-cli_2.1.3-2_all.deb
wget: relocation error: wget: symbol ENGINE_load_builtin_engines version OPENSSL_1_1_0 not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.1 with link time reference
```

I managed to resolve the wget error, by correcting some incorrectly linked libraries for OpenSSL:

```
# ldd `which openssl`
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffccaebf000)
        libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/lib/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007fa859c29000)
        libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007fa859546000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa859327000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa858f36000)
        libgcompat.so.0 => /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/lib/libgcompat.so.0 (0x00007fa859c0b000)
        libc.so => /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/lib/libc.so (0x00007fa859b68000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa859a85000)
# echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/lib/plexmediaserver:/usr/lib/plexmediaserver/lib
# unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
# wget http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/speedtest-cli/speedtest-cli_2.1.3-2_all.deb
--2021-12-01 11:54:51--  http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/speedtest-cli/speedtest-cli_2.1.3-2_all.deb
Resolving ftp.au.debian.org (ftp.au.debian.org)... 150.203.164.37, 2001:388:1034:2900::25
Connecting to ftp.au.debian.org (ftp.au.debian.org)|150.203.164.37|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 24596 (24K) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: ‘speedtest-cli_2.1.3-2_all.deb’

speedtest-cli_2.1.3-2_all.deb   100%[====================================================>]  24.02K  --.-KB/s    in 0.02s

2021-12-01 11:54:51 (1.12 MB/s) - ‘speedtest-cli_2.1.3-2_all.deb’ saved [24596/24596]
```

The speedtest-cli program uses a Python3 script, and I've made sure python3-openssl is up to date, as is ca-certificates, openssl, and speedtest-cli itself (I even downloaded a newer .deb than was available in my repo, to test).

I removed the openssl package in an attempt to obtain a clean slate, but this also removed a lot of the OS (including the ubuntu-server package!). I re-installed openssl and ubuntu-server, then did a full `apt full-upgrade`, and rebooted, but the error prevails.

I'm in a little over my head with linked libraries and whatnot, but what I *think* has happened is that Plex Media Server has blasted itself over the top of some OpenSSL config, but I'm not sure how to see exactly what the problem is, or fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I would check `/etc/profile*/*` for any `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` export, also check systemd for any plexmedia services which are run.

Comment: @Bib there is a Plex service but LD_LIBRARY_PATH isn't set in any of:
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/plexmediaserver.service
/lib/systemd/system/plexmediaserver.service
/usr/lib/plexmediaserver/lib/plexmediaserver.service

This is probably a symptom rather than the cause, though. I can't use dig, curl, or anything like that without it throwing "OPENSSL_1_1_0 not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.1", but I'm not really sure what that means.